# What's the road map to become a good programmer of microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, programming

I'm kind of new to microcontroller science and programming, but do some small project with ESP 8266 .
I want to create a anti theft reliable system with some sensors like microwave sensors.
Could someone please help me that which methods i should Observe for this project?

I just want a summary of the things i should to observe. Also what's kind of test I should use for this?

I will be very thankful if somebody help me and show a road map to me.

Comment: This question is too broad and it solicits opinions. Both are off-topic. To become good in something you have to practice, but the ways to professionalism differ vastly. Concerning your project there are hundreds of aspects and pitfalls. I recommend to try some project management first. Define your (S.M.A.R.T.) goals and environments and then ask specific questions. Then you will have gained reasonable knowledge to proceed on the path that fits yourself best.

Answer (score 4):

It would be impossible to do this justice in a single answer. In a nutshell you should start small and work your way up.

Get a reliable hardware/software setup for the device you're going to work with.

Choose a simple programming set e.g. arduino (vs micropython vs lua) to get started. Be prepared to switch to more advanced tooling as you gain experience.

Fully understand the programming model and libraries in use along with the capabilities of the device e.g. sleep mode, connecting to wifi, writing to serial connections, ...

Start out just using switch for input, multimeter or LEDs for output to check your understanding and use basic hardware.

Then once you are comfortable and know how to program the device to get the outcomes you want you will be in a position to start to incorporate more complicated setups including sensors.

If you try to go to complex to quickly you'll get frustrated as a result of lack of experience and lose interest...

Good luck!

Comment: Absolutely. Start with flashing a LED. Then controlling the LED with a switch.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer ... for example one thing make me confused is how i can automatically restart Esp 12 when errors comes after one day of work , how i should detect this

Comment: @hossein. That is a different question. Don't add requirements into the comments. If its relevant to your question then edit the question. Otherwise ask a new question and link to this if it's relevant.

Comment: For any readers who want to know, that new question has been asked by the OP [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/530479/how-to-detect-error-and-restart-microcontroller-for-embedded-system-with-esp-12).